# Почему не подставляются значения в ${}?

Tags: javascript

```js
const person = {
  userName: 'Alex',
  commentsQty: 0,
  hasSignedAgreement: false
}

const userInfo = ({
  userName,
  commentsQty
}) => {
  if (!commentsQty) {
    return 'User ${userName} has no comments';
  }
  return 'User ${userName} has ${commentsQty}';
}

console.log(userInfo(person));
```

Почему то выводит:

> User ${userName} has no comments

, хотя я ожидал

> User Alex has no comments

Comment: нужные кавычки на букве Ё. ``

Answer (score 2):

Потому что данные конструкции работают в шаблонных строках, которые начинаются с **обратной кавычки**, а не с прямой

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#description